# Telerik RadRibbonBar - comportamento estranho

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Ao configurar textos e imagens numa `RibbonBar`, junto com seus alinhamentos, repentinamente a janela se tornou demasiado pequena, impedindo toda forma de se aumentar seu tamanho (Windows form, `Telerik v2014.1.228.40`, Visual Studio 2013, C#). Isto num projeto iniciado há várias semanas e que funcionava bem nas versões anteriores tanto do VS como do Telerik.

Solução no meu comentário abaixo.

Answer (score 1):

Como achei a solução, aqui vai: trata-se de um problema conhecido nesta primeira versão da biblioteca Telerik e só ocorre se WindowsState= Maximized em tempo de programação. Correção: setar isto em tempo de execução. No evento load funcionou bem

this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;